# Find page break tag

Tags: php, regex, string

How to find page break tag in php string

```
<!-- pagebreak -->
```

and then cut everything which is after also whit this tag?

This is my sample string:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consec tetuer adipiscing elit praesent ves tibulum moles tie lacusenean non ummy hendrer maur hasellus porta usce suscipit varius mi.</p> <p><!-- pagebreak --></p> <p>Lorem ipsum next.</p>...
```

and what I want to get after:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consec tetuer adipiscing elit praesent ves tibulum moles tie lacusenean non ummy hendrer maur hasellus porta usce suscipit varius mi.</p>
```

Comment: I cannot understand your question, can you give more info.

Comment: Read the PHP documentation about String-methods (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) maybe you could use strrpos() or something like this.

BTW: `<!-- pagebreak -->` is not a HTML tag. It is a HTML comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) and [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/strrpos):

```
$result = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '<!-- pagebreak -->'));
```

This will cut off everything after the **last** occurence of `<!-- pagebreak -->`. If you want to cut off everything after the first occurence, simply use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) instead.

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/56679)

Comment: But how if he have more than one page break, so upoate your answer !

Comment: @user2746186: Glad to have been of help :)